# Stored procedure for nested subquery in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in need of stored procedure, I have searched but I didn't get any relevant code.

My requirement is the stored procedure wants to loop the first subquery based on inner subquery.

```
Select *
from StockInward,
     Setup  
where StockInward.StockLocation=Setup.Id    
  AND ProductId in( Select ProductId 
                    from ProductOutward  
                    where Orderid ='38')
```

The sample table data and output below:

`Product Outward` table

```
Id Orderid  Productid  Qty
1   38         7        2
2   38         6        1
```

`Stockinward` table

```
Id ProductId BranchId  Qty
1      7       1        12
2      6       1        2
3      7       2        2
```

`Setup` table

```
BranchId  Branchname
1           Xyz
2           ABC
```

The output need to be:

```
ProductId     Branches
7             Xyz(12)   Abc(2 )   
6             Xyz(2)    -
```

Comment: it might be useful to add some sample data and your desired output as it's unclear what you're asking here

Comment: too many confusing typo on the sample data to get the clear meaning of the question. BranchId ?= 12; Branchname ?= 'ABC'

Comment: Have to get branchname that matches the branchid